# Carrie Fisher Memorial Answer Bounty

Tags: discussion

The passing of Carrie Fisher has hit a lot of science fiction fans hard; obviously, her character was a significant part of the popularity of one of the best science fiction movie franchises in history.

As we are a Q&A site, the best way (IMO) for us to remember Carrie Fisher is to highlight some of those awesome questions and answers that we have thanks to her. So, if you have a favorite answer to a question *about Princess Leia*, post it here and let us know why you like it so much.

---

All three of the suggestions were good ones so I have awarded a bounty to all three. Thanks for your participation.

Comment: The answer with the most votes on main, or on meta?

Comment: It's been more than a week ...

Answer (score 17):

Despite not being into Star Wars, I enjoyed the answers to this question:

[Why does Leia's accent change during A New Hope?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2903/31394)

I'm nominating it for a memorial bounty because it makes a connection between **Carrie Fisher IRL** (which is who we're commemorating) and **events within the Star Wars universe** (which is what makes it on-topic for this site). It's interesting from both in-universe and out-of-universe points of view.

The top three answers are all pretty good, but if I had to choose one for a bounty, it would be [Omegacron's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103934/31394), because it's been underappreciated so far compared to the other two.

Comment: I would also support giving a bounty to Omegacron's answer, since it extensively details the in-universe answer and still mentions the out-of-universe answer.

Answer (score 16):

I pick this question's top answer:

[Is there really "No Underwear In Space?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112767/31178)

The quote in question is how Carrie came to her famous "drowned in moonlight, strangled by her own bra" obituary line.

The current top answer by @CHEESE also features a hand drawn red circle and creeping on Anakin's undies.

It's funny. She was funny. I remember watching her roast fellow celebs and killing it.

Comment: I'm flattered.  Although I would like to make it clear that it was @ibid who drew the circle due to my technical...inavailability at that time.

Comment: @CHEESE I don't know if that's better or worse

Answer (score 6):

My previous nomination was intended mainly to draw attention to an interesting *question*. For an excellent *answer* to a question which is surely of interest to many Star Wars fans, how about:

[Did Luke or Leia ever feel romantic attraction to each other?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120964/31394)

Possibly incestuous kisses are one of the biggest controversies in Star Wars, and this answer goes into a great deal of detail, backed up clearly at every stage by canon quotes, about exactly how much incestuous feeling there really was between Luke and Leia. It deserves more recognition than it's had.

Comment: Kisses? Plural?

Comment: @CreationEdge - I remember at least two off-hand: Leia kissed Luke when running from stormtroopers on Death Star before the Tarzan maneuver "for luck". Then she kissed him on Hoth to get Han upset. I won't even go into "Splinter of the mind's eye".